# Where or what are the instructions for installing FMOD Ex for Linux to use in g++?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, g++, fmod

This isn't really a programming question per se, but it is related. I'm looking for the instructions on how to install FMOD.

I want to do extra credit for my computer graphics assignment - sound effects. A teammate wants me to go with something simple, and he suggested that I use FMOD Ex. (If you guys can think of something better, do suggest it, but so far FMOD looks more promising compared to SDL, OpenAL, etc.)

Right now I'm having a really hard time finding the instructions for installing the latest version of FMOD (audio content creation tool) on Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32-bit) so that I can use it in g++ with OpenGL. I checked out this YouTube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avGxNkiAS9g, but it's for Windows. Then, there is a Ubuntu Forums thread which redirected me to this page: https://wiki.debian.org/FMOD, and it has some dated instructions. I've downloaded FMOD Ex v. 4.44.24, which I believe is the latest version. Now I'm looking at eight libraries: libfmodex.so, libfmodex64.so, libfmodex64-4.44.24.so, libfmodex-4.44.24.so, libfmodexL.so, libfmodexL64.so, libfmodexL64-4.44.24.so, libfmodexL-4.44.24.so ... not knowing what to do. I've looked everywhere I could think of: here, YouTube, Google, Ubuntu forums, ... and came up with zilch. I can't think of any other place to ask this question.

If you do know how to install FMOD off the top of your head, drop me a line.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask on [FMOD forum](http://www.fmod.org/forum/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Thanks. I forgot that could be an option. This page <http://www.fmod.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=15583&p=52366&hilit=fmod+install#p52366> looks like something I should focus on, albeit my Ubuntu's version and architecture are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the .so files in /usr/local/lib/, the header files in /usr/local/include/fmodex/, and you're good to go.

Comment: So, ... `sudo cp ~/fmodapi44424linux/api/lib/*.so /usr/local/lib/` and `sudo cp ~/fmodapi44424linux/api/inc/* /usr/local/include/fmodex` ... did I get that right?

Comment: Do I need to export something to PATH in .bashrc or what I have (`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib`) should be enough?

Comment: @Andrey /usr/local/lib should already be in the default linker search path, so you shouldn't need to do anything. This is why I suggested /usr/local in the first place. You can check /etc/ld.so.conf to see whether it's actually listed in there. In case it's not, you can add a file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ that contains a line with that path. Remember to run ldconfig afterwards so that your changes are applied.

Comment: I ran `ls -a` on ~/usr/local/etc, and it does not show ld.so.conf.d . The directory is empty, and this laptop has not undergone any infections (that I remember). Is it supposed to be that way? I don't think I can edit the file.

Comment: @Andrey ~/usr/local/etc? Your home directory shouldn't be brought into this. The path is /usr/local/lib, and ld.so.conf is in /etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40409/discussion-between-andrey-and-nikos-c)